How to NOT use Gradle version catalogs by default for new projects in Android Studio?

I just recently updated my Android Studio to Jellyfish | 2023.3.1. It's been a while since I created a new project using Project Wizard. I'm trying to build a new Compose project and it doesn't matter whether you choose Groovy or Kotlin DSL for the Build Configuration language, by default Android Studio creates the new project with version catalogs.
The version catalogs are better suited for multi-module projects even by Google standards and the official Android documentation.

Gradle version catalogs enable you to add and maintain dependencies and plugins in a scalable way. Using Gradle version catalogs makes managing dependencies and plugins easier when you have multiple modules.

I searched in Android Studio settings, Google, and SO. Still, I didn't find any options to sabotage this forced behavior when you want or when the project is just a simple single-module monolithic project.

There currently is no way to change that. Templates are now fetched from a "locked" API, and there is no local storage for them, so you can't edit them at will to revert back. The only way to do so is simply by removing the libs.versions.toml file manually and adding your dependencies to your gradle file as you used to.

Good suggestion but that's only a workaround that I need to do for every new project.
